# Annual Salesforce MVP Nominations are Open - 2019

Tags: discussion, mvp

## Public service announcement:

The [MVP nominations](https://www.salesforce.com/blog/2018/11/salesforce-MVP-nominations-2019.html?d=70130000000tP4G) are open from now until January 11th, 2019.

As per the change last year, this is now an annual process. [Source](https://www.salesforce.com/campaign/mvp/)

> New MVP classes will be welcomed **once per year**, and anyone can nominate an MVP during the **once-yearly** nomination period.

Feel free to nominate those who have made an exceptional contribution to the SFSE community. That could be users or moderators or anyone else who has helped you on your way.

See also: [Top 5 Things to Know About How We Choose Our MVPs](https://www.salesforce.com/blog/2016/02/how-we-choose-salesforce-mvps.html)

## What is a Salesforce MVP?

> Salesforce MVPs are lifelong learners who go above and beyond to share their expertise and help the entire community blaze trails. You can learn all about our current Salesforce MVPs and connect with them via the Trailblazer Community [Salesforce MVP](http://trailblazer.salesforce.com/mvp) page.

Comment: Is David Reed among us yet?

Comment: @AdrianLarson No. But he appears to have a [profile](https://mvp-app-prod.herokuapp.com/campaigns/7011I000000N1JrQAK/nominations/new?nominee=IUIhVFRzTjFUVFRUVGJjUXRCRjgwIUUh) that you can expand on for your nomination.

Comment: Is Keith Clarke and Eric Kintzer(cropredy) already part of this?

Comment: @TusharSharma, both of them are already MVPs. We will definitely like to see new MVPs from SFSE for their exceptional contributions. I will be voting for few members.

Comment: Am I right in thinking that you should still vote for current MVPs if they've continued the same level of contribution and awesomeness in the current year, in order for them to *retain* their MVP status?

Comment: @RobCowell Current MVPs automatically go into a separate renewals process. You can provide contribution details if you want, but it isn't required.

Comment: Cropredy is not an MVP -- or at least no one ever told me :-)

Comment: Had to chose between Adam Spriggs, Eliot Harper and Gortonington, since i havent found the last i chose Adam. All of them made me learn a lot of stuff, thanks to all other hard working sfse members aswell.

Comment: @JohannesSchapdick Both Adam and Eliot are already MVPs.

Comment: They still deserve it and I don’t know if a MVP status get revoked at some point -> therefore I gave one of them my vote